# extract xml nodes as table with xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I have a pretty simple but huge xml (more than 50.000 lines). I want to extract just one repeated node as table (ring). Take into account this is an example. The real file has more than 300 elements inside "ring" node, so I try to avoid to write command for extraction element by element if that is possible.

Here a little example

```
<xml>
<root>
  <ration>
    <ring>
      <id  value="1"/>
      <date  value="2021-01-01"/>
      <price  value="435"/>
    </ring>
  </ration>
</root>
<root>
  <ration>
    <ring>
      <id  value="14"/>
      <date  value="2021-02-01"/>
      <price  value="745"/>
    </ring>
  </ration>
</root>
</xml>
```

what I want to achieve is:
this xmlstarlet command is working and I get the proper result but now think on doing it 300 times (for every element I have to insert the call into the concat part). I need a more simple approach.

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m '//root/ration/ring' -v "concat(id/@value,',',date/@value,',',price/@value)"  -n file.xml

id, date, price
1, 2021-01-01, 435
14, 2021-02-01, 745
```

Comment: I don't think you can do it with xmlstarlet (which supports only xpath 1.0), but it can be done with xpath 2.0 and above - something like xidel, if available.

Comment: Tried some approaches but at last, I got all elements name querying with xmlstarlet, compose a concat query in bash and execute the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since you asked. Nevertheless...

```shell
xmlstarlet sel -T \
    -t -m '//root[1]/ration/ring/*[boolean(@value)]' \
    -v 'substring(", ", 1, 2*(position() != 1))' -v 'local-name()' -b -nl \
    -t -m '//root' -m 'ration/ring/*[boolean(@value)]' \
    -v 'substring(", ", 1, 2*(position() != 1))' -v '@value' -b -nl \
    file.xml
```

Output:

```
id, date, price
1, 2021-01-01, 435
14, 2021-02-01, 745
```

Template #1 emits the header, #2 the data. `-m` expressions #1 and #3 match child elements of `ring` having a `@value` attribute. Using `-m` and `-b` together does the trick. If `@value` is replaced with `@*` all attributes are selected; with a predicate such as `@*[name()="value" or name()="otherval"]` selection can be fine-tuned.

Separation of values takes more work in XSLT 1.0 than in 2.0: in this case a `substring` function call returns an empty string for the first value where `position() != 1` is false (converted to number 0), and a 2-character string (comma and space) for the following where it is true (1).

By the way, tag / PI names beginning with `xml` in any lower/upper combination are [reserved](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#sec-common-syn).